# Removing hidden character at end of SQL server field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a strange situation displaying value from SQL server. There is a value stored in SQL server 2008 field which is hidden when queried from server and shown in Management Studio (see below).

Test template 2​

But when displayed on a screen in HTML editor it is showing as ? (see below)

Test template 2?

When I check for ascii value it shows 63. Not sure how user got this special value into this field in SQL server. When I test by entering ? into input field and display it works fine without any issues. 
I don't want to blindly remove last character from this field. I am trying to determine a solution to identify this invisible value and remove it either while storing or displaying. 
Any solution is greatly appreciated.

As comments below suggests this turned out to be Unicode 8203 (zero width space).
My next question is how to replace this Unicode 8203 in one statement in T-SQL without parsing through each character?

Comment: What happens if you look at `UNICODE` value for that char instead of `ASCII` ?

Comment: Unicode value shows as 8203

Comment: Here u go, it's a Unicode char "ZERO WIDTH SPACE" probably got copied along with the text from an Office-like app. Now if you need to remove it - you can replace this specific char.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) to remove the zero-width space character:

```
-- setup unicode string containing zero-width character
DECLARE @UnicodeReplace NVARCHAR(5) = N'Test' + NCHAR(8203);

-- check that unicode string length is 5,
-- and prove existence of zero-width space character matching unicode 8203
SELECT @UnicodeReplace AS String,
       LEN(@UnicodeReplace) AS Length,
       UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@UnicodeReplace, 5, 1)) AS UnicodeValue

-- replace and prove the unicode string length is reduced to 4
SELECT REPLACE(@UnicodeReplace, NCHAR(8203), N''),
       LEN(REPLACE(@UnicodeReplace, NCHAR(8203), N'')) AS Length;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d4bbd/1)

Comment: I run into this answer while trying to replace the ltr-marker (UTF-8: 0xE2 0x80 0x8E, Html Entity: &#8206;) in T-SQL. The above code snippet works, but if I replace NCHAR(8203) with NCHAR(8206) replacing works no more. Am I using the wrong decimal code for the ltr-marker or could this be an issue in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

Such characters could not be replaced if database collation has default values like this: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. In such cases this command could work:

set @word=replace(@word collate Latin1_General_100_BIN2, nchar(8205),N'')

Comment: check for nchar(8205)